# react onClick not firing in multi elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have problem with the onClick in  element
the onClick event work for the toggle box
but not fire when I use on the link element

This is my code: (it's a small drop-down component)

```
handleClick: function(e) {
        console.log('try')
    },

    renderLink: function(list){
        if (list.type === 'lang') {
            return   <a onClick={this.handleClick} target={!this.props.newTab?'':'_blank'}>{list.title}</a>;
        } else {
            return   <a  href={list.url} target={!this.props.newTab?'':'_blank'}>{list.title}</a>;
        }
    },


    render: function() {
        var list;
        if (this.state.isOpened) {
            var listItems = [];
            for (var i=0; i<this.props.list.length; i++) {
                listItems.push(
                    <li   key={i}>
                        {this.renderLink(this.props.list[i])}
                    </li>
                );
            }

            list = (
                <ul className="selector-list">
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className={'selector '+this.props.id} onClick={this.toggleList}>
                <div className="down-arrow"></div>
                <div className="title">{this.props.title}</div>
                {list}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` as an anchor tag will reload the page

Comment: Can you reproduce a test environment in a jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: have you bound `handleClick` in the component's constructor?

Comment: if I try to add the element inside the main div without the if and the for to onclick work but in the if and the loop not working

Comment: problem solved its was a click event on the all compnent